# Server returns 204 (no content) but api gateway returns 200 (success)

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-api-gateway

I am a newbie with AWS.

Suppose we have an endpoint like this:

```
/attraction/search-by-rsql-no-point?query=...
```

if `query` does not match any entries from the database, my server returns me an empty response and `204` as status code, and this is working correctly.

As soon as I managed this resource via AWS API Gateway, this is always giving me `200` status code, even I am expecting `204` (or any other kind of codes).

[image: Method execution]

- How can I fix?

I have read some similar questions and I figured out that proxy integration can be a solution. But I can't understand how can I implement this and solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, use proxy integration: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html
Return from lambda function should be in this format:

{
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
    "multiValueHeaders": { "headerName": ["headerValue", "headerValue2", ...], ... },
    "body": "..."
}

Comment: And how shall I modify that method execution when I will have created my lambda function?

Comment: Click on Integration Request and check **Use Lambda Proxy integration**

Comment: I am stuck, though

Comment: Where do you get stuck?